# expected conv1d_1_input to have shape (15, 512) but got array with shape (4, 512)

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, prediction, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on a sentiment analysis project in python with keras using CNN and word2vec as an embedding method.
according to my code, I set my input shape, 15 and 512 so when I want to predict the polarity of a new sentence say:"I am so sorry" for example, with the length: 4 - I face this error:

> expected conv1d_1_input to have shape (15, 512) but got array with shape (4, 512)
>   and this is a part of my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same', 
input_shape=(15, 512)))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu')
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

all I can do is making new python file and load all my related models such as word2vec ... and change the input shape on it like this:

```
model111 = Sequential()
model111.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same', 
input_shape=(len(input), 512)))
model111.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model111.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model111.add(Dropout(0.5))
model111.add(Flatten())
model111.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

I wanna know whether this method is ok or not?? any efficient solution would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have inputs with a size smaller than your model is expecting, you need to do padding (i.e adding zeros to the end of input array to complete the expected size before give to model. There is a keras function to do that:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
input_array = pad_sequences(input_array, maxlen=max_tweet_length, padding='post')
```

And then, reshape your data to so that it fits the expected spatiality by CNN:

```
input_array = input_array.reshape(input_array.shape + (1,))
```

Comment: Are you sure that pad_sequences work with CNN? as far as I know, CNN doesn't support this method and I should make it directly and when I do that I face this error: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 15)

Comment: Yes. It works! The problem is that CNN expects a 3d Tensor, there is no relation to padding. Try to add 1 more dimension to your input tensor after padding. Like this:  ` input_array = input_array.reshape(input_array.shape + (1,)))`

Comment: thanks for your solution- since I'm kinda new to this field would you please  explain a little about this sentence: you need to add 1 more dimension to your tensor

Comment: It is because the CNN expects a tensor in the shape (batch_size, steps, input_dim) and you are giving a tensor with this shape (batch_size, steps)

Comment: In practice, all you are doing is reshape your data to have a spatial dimension for Conv1d makes sense.

Comment: now i face this error:   Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 15, 512, 1)

Comment: Try to change this : model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same',  input_shape=(15, 512))). To this: model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same', 
input_shape=(15, )))

Comment: you mean change it in this way: model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same', input_shape=(max_tweet_length, vector_size,1)) i insert 1 at the end of input shape and face this new error:  Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Comment: Nop. Just put max_tweet_length on input_shape.  Exactly like this : ......input_shape(max_tweet_length, )

Comment: and this change: model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same', input_shape=(15,))) give me a similar error:  Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
before i get any new sentence to my model

Comment: Hmm try to put (max_tweet_length, 1) then

Comment: i did what you said and this is another error:ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have shape (15, 1) but got array with shape (15, 512) as i told you i fixed input shape :(15,512)

Comment: Last attempt then, try (1,15).

Comment: unfortunately when i put : model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same', input_shape=(1,15))) in my code i face this error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have shape (1, 15) but got array with shape (15, 512)

Comment: Or (1, 15, 512)

Comment: i think there might be some reshaping method for my input say something that you mentioned before, Do yo have any idea?

Comment: when i put(1,15,512) i face this error again: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4  :(((

Comment: thanks a million, there was some stupid mistake - now it's fixed

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

According to what  **Eduardo Soares** said I should padding my input sentence directly or with the pad_sequences function as below:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
input_array = pad_sequences(input_array, maxlen=max_tweet_length, padding='post')
```

and after that I got this error:

> when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but
>   got array with shape (1, 15)

which wasn't related to ex-error, from my understanding this is something related to input shape so I should reshape my input after padding(here input_array) so I tried it with this code:

```
input_array = input_array.reshape(input_array.shape + (1,))
```

and everything goes right! hope this gonna be helpful